# Laravel 5.8 trying to make AJAX call to delete comment fails to load

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to use an AJAX call to delete a comment in my recipe application. 
It keeps giving me a `405 error: Method not allowed`. Not sure where it is breaking, it looks alright to me. Could somebody please take a look?

**Blade view**

```
@foreach($recipe->comments as $comment)
    <div>
        @if($comment->name == Auth()->user()->name)
            <p><a href="/user/{{$comment->name}}">{{$comment->name}}</a></p>
            <p>{{$comment->comment}}</p>
            <button class="deleteComment" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" >Delete Comment</button>
        @else
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Custom js file**

```
// Delete Comments AJAX 

$(".deleteComment").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var token = $(this).data("token");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/comment/delete/"+id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "_method": 'DELETE',
            "_token": token,
        },
        success: function ()
        {
            console.log("it Work");
        }
    });
    console.log("It failed");
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::delete('comment/delete/{id}', 'CommentsController@destroy');
```

**CommentController@destroy**

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        Comment::destroy($id);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Anyone able to see where it is breaking??

Comment: can you add the error you're getting? is it server side or in the browser

Comment: I'm just getting the console.log(It failed) that's at the end of my AJAX call in case it doesn't work.

Comment: return redirect()->back();  this is the problem you return any json object it will work

Comment: @ShofiullahBabor What do you mean? Should I not redirect back?

Comment: yes, because you receive in ajax json but it not return json but return redirect it is error. you try this return ['status' => true] then see what will output

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Throws me a 404 error.

Comment: your request reach to controller ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192533/discussion-between-carlstrom96-and-shofiullah-babor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Route::delete('comment/delete/{id}', 'CommentsController@destroy');
 public function destroy(Request $request,$id) 
 { 
     Comment::destroy($id); 
     return ['status'=> true] ; 
 }
```

add this code

Comment: Thank you!! How can I make the AJAX request update the DOM without reloading page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about laravel because I've used it just a couple of times and I'm still learning about, but you can try to change the request type from `delete` to `post`. the DELETE HTTP request method has no body to carry some data and you need to pass the comment id to the controller. This should work:

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/comment/delete/"+id,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "_method": 'DELETE',
            "_token": token,
        },
        success: function ()
        {
            console.log("it Work");
        }
    });
    console.log("It failed");
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. Still hits the console.log("It failed"); at the bottom of the script...

Comment: I think the problem is with the route, what happen if you pass the id inside the request without attaching it to the url?

Comment: Hmm possibly. I tried removing it from the url in the route and I get: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment/delete/8 404 (Not Found). So it's adding the comment id correctly to the POST request, but after that it fails.

Comment: Have you tried also to modify `"_method": 'DELETE'` to `"_method": 'POST'` ?

Comment: Yes sir I just tried it. Still gives me that 404 error

Comment: Strange, try debug the request with the network tab of the dev tool. As it was written in a comment you need to check if the requests are correctly  reaching the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that. Instead of `method: 'DELETE'` you rather used `type: 'DELETE'` hence JQuery doesn't make the request at all because it has no method.
this is because in newer versions of jquery **type** was changed into **method**. Use type if you're using jquery version prior to 1.9.0